# Unable to make minitoc and every chapter reference in CUED PhD thesis template

Tags: bibliographies, templates, minitoc

Concerning the [Thesis template by kks32](https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template):

I try to use the `minitoc` package to get a table of contents for each chapter along with a bibliography by using  `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]`. Both do not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As sooften with templates, they predefine stuff that is incompatible with certain pakages.

You can use package `etoc` to create local tocs for each chapter.

[image: bikiteroMinitoc]

Add the following at the end of your preamble.

```
\usepackage{etoc}                                                                                                                              
\etocsettocstyle{\subsection*{This Chapter contains:}}{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}}
```

After the chapter heading, use `\localtableofcontents` to print the toc for the current chapter.

---

Concerning the bibliographies: Ignore everything the template suggests to do by putting percent signs at the start of those line, i.e. commenting them out. Refer to [that part of the wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber#Bibliographies_per_Section_or_Chapter)
or [my forum post](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=99099#p99099). There have been another forum thread, a github issue and Overleaf comments by the same user discussing this question. I cannot find any of them.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369094/bibliography-issue Apparently, the user wiped away any trace.

Comment: the question you linked to in your comment is tagged `deleted by Community♦ Nov 15 at 3:00 (RemoveAbandonedClosed)` and `This question was automatically deleted.`, should we draw moderator attention to undelete it? (it had been `closed as unclear what you're asking Nov 5 at 10:58`)

Comment: @jfbu the question cannot be answered as there is no problem. Same here, probably OP didn't run tge required tool. It is a two fold question, the first about minitoc is a good one.

Comment: ok, that other question looked indeed unclear ...

Comment: TOC part is working now, but Bibliography part not working when i put the lines that given in this link http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=99099#p99099 @Johannes_B

Comment: @biki go through that wikibook page step by step. Once you see a bibliography generated and understand how and why, go back to the template.

Comment: Yes I go through the wikibook and it was working according to their format. But when i put this two commands `\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}`
`\addbibresource{Reference/references.bib}` after the `\documentclass` it is not working giving me error as "! LaTeX Error: Command \bibhang already defined." @Johannes_B

Comment: @BikiTeron You need `custombib` option.

Comment: Is like this `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,times,numbered,print,index,custombib]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}` @Johannes_B

Comment: Now both each chapter TOC and each chapter references are working after removing the numbered from class option, thank you so much @Johannes_B

Comment: @BikiTeron You cannot have two different options for one task. Should be obvious ;-)